# Will angular update model value when the viewValue is invalid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form and an input. The input is bound to a value in the controller via ng-model. Now I have a custom validator which invalidates the input's value in certain circumstances. But I can't find out if the model value is updated if my validator invalidates the value. I can't $watch in my controller so I have no idea how I could find out this. Pseudocode here:

(hint: snippet won't run)

```js
class Controller {
  
  constructor() {
    this.myVal = 0;  
  }
  
}
```

```html
<input type="number"
               id="max"
               name="max"
               ng-model="ctrl.myVal"
               restrict-value="form.min.$viewValue" />
```

Now my problem can be seen. The restrict-value directive will register a $validator on the ngModel and will return false if the value of the input field is greater than another field (min). If max's value is lower than min's I don't want to update the model value. Can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In browsers that follow the HTML5 specification, input[number] does not work as expected with ngModelOptions.allowInvalid. If a non-number is entered in the input, the browser will report the value as an empty string, which means the view / model values in ngModel and subsequently the scope value will also be an empty string.

from [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D)